# Power BI Get Data From Multiple Google BigQuery Projects

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I have 2 projects in Google Big Query.

```
select * FROM `project1.analytics_1.Table1`

select * FROM `project2.analytics_2.Table2`
```

When I get data from Google Big Query, the first one works but for the second one I am getting `The key didn't match any rows in the table`.

[image]

Comment: Is the table empty?

Comment: @Marcus data is there in table. The issue is that Power BI not accepting multiple project/dataset quires.

Comment: Then perhaps paste your sample queries. I would expect this type of error when there is a certain expectation by the engine for some column to exist (since it is referred to in some way) , but it does not exist in your actual table. This error message is meaningless without additional information.

Comment: I already posted the query above.

Comment: That is the SQL query, not the Power Query queries.

Comment: Yea, this is SQL I am using this in `Get Data`. As I said said before it is working for 1 project but not for second one,

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch have you checked the M code in Advanced Editor? You should be able to find a statement like `#"your-gcp-project-id" = Source{[Name="your-gcp-project-id"]}[Data]`. Is that set up correctly for both of your queries?

Comment: @KosukeSakai tried with project and got error.